# What's the name for the physical attribute that would describe the flexibility of a chain mail?

Tags: terminology, material-science, definition

The individual links of a [chain mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(armour)) are pretty rigid.

When deforming a piece of chain mail following its intended use, its flexibility doesn't rely on the elastic or plastic properties of the underlying material.

Its simply constructed in a way that allows for high deformability without damage.

I'm not interested in chain mails specifically, just want to find out if there is a word or unit of measure or something for objects that are constructed out of rigid materials but result in a flexible whole?